# SAS PROC SQL Replace substring

Tags: sas

I'm trying to update a field using PROC SQL. What needs to happen is based a criteria a field of binary values needs to have the nth value changed.

Example: 00100 updated to 00110.

I was hoping to use the substr command, but it is not functioning as expected.

```
Data Test;
    Input Binary $;
    Datalines;
    000
    001
    010
    100
    ;
Run;

Proc SQL;
Select Case When substr(Binary,2,1) eq '0' Then Substr(Binary,2) = '1' End as Binary2
From Test;
Quit;
```

Instead of returning the updated Binary variable, this query is only returning the second character in the string, not updated.

Comment: Based on your code I get the message: `NOTE: A CASE expression has no ELSE clause. Cases not accounted for by the WHEN clauses will result in a missing value for the CASE expression.`.  Perhaps fixing this issue first will shed some light on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT` cannot use the left-side-of-equals SUBSTR in the way you are using it.  In fact, including the equal sign makes it do something very different from what you're thinking - it's not returning the second character of the string, but it's returning a TRUE or FALSE.  That happens to match the second character, because your characters are 1 or 0 and you're testing it to 1, but still.

```
Proc SQL;
Select Case When substr(Binary,2,1) eq '0' Then 
case when Substr(Binary,2) = '1' then return 1 else 0 end
End as Binary2
From Test;
Quit;
```

That's what SAS is doing.

If you want to do this in SQL, you'll have to construct the substring, or preferably do this in the data step which allows you to use the left-hand-substr.

This would work, for example:

```
Proc SQL;
Select cats(substr(binary,1,1),'1',substr(binary,3)) as Binary2
From Test;
Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of actual bit flagging use functions from the bitwise family

- `BOR (value, mask)` to turn on bits
- `BAND (value, BNOT (mask))` to turn off bits
- `BXOR (value, mask)` to toggle bits

Here are some sample operations demonstrating the use of these bitwise functions.  Use the `diagnostic` columns to observer the rows where a sample operation occurred, and what the original value was before the operation.

Bitwise functions argument value range is 0..2<sup>32</sup>-1.  Variables, of course, are still double precision for storage purposes.

```
Data have;
  case_id + 1;
  Input
BitFlag binary3.; Datalines;
000
001
010
100
;
Run;

* extended sample data, every bit combination for 10 bits representing binary flag0-flag9;
data have;
  do bitflag = 0 to 2**10-1;
    output;
  end;
  stop;
  array diagnostic(10);
  format bitflag diag: binary10.;
run;
```

Sample operations

```
proc sql;
```

- turn on bit-5 of evey flag where bit-5 is off;

```
  update have
  set 
    bitflag = bor ( bitflag , 2**5 )
  , diagnostic1 = bitflag
  where
    band ( bitflag , 2**5 ) = 0
  ;
```

- turn off bit-7 of evey flag where bit-1 is off and bit-3 is on;

```
  update have
  set 
    bitflag = band ( bitflag , bnot ( 2**7 ) )
  , diagnostic2 = bitflag
  where 
        band ( bitflag , 2**1 ) = 0
    and band ( bitflag , 2**3 ) > 0
  ;
```

- turn on bit-8 unconditionally and turn off bit-9 unconditionally;

```
  update have
  set 
    bitflag = bor (
                band ( bitflag , bnot ( 2**9 ) ),
                2**8
              )
  , diagnostic3 = bitflag
  ;
```

- toggle bit-0 and bit-1 unconditionally;

```
  update have
  set 
    bitflag = bxor ( bitflag, bor (2**0 , 2**1 ) )
  , diagnostic4 = bitflag
  ;
```

Note: General SAS understands hexadecimal literals in the form of `#####x`, but does not have a syntax for understanding of bit-literals. You can use this macro to code with a bit-literal interpretation of a literal bit-string.

```
  %macro BIT_LITERAL(bitstring);
    %sysfunc(inputn(&bitstring,binary32.));
  %mend;
  %put NOTE: %BIT_LITERAL(1);
  %put NOTE: %BIT_LITERAL(1001);
  ----- LOG -----
  NOTE: 1
  NOTE: 9
```

NOTE: DATA Step does understand bit masks for bit testing, but does not have a bit-literal syntax for value assignment.

`Proc DS2` lets a SAS session use DS2 Language that *does* have syntax for binary constants expressed in hex or binary ( `x'hex-string'` and `b'bit-string'`)